# php & ajax retriving post data failed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I got some very strange issues while I'm trying send post data to `php` via `xmlhttp request`:

Here is javascript code:

```
function getHeaterDailyConfig(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var d = new Date()
    now = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate()].join('-');
    var reqArgs = "isDateRequested=1&date=" + now;
    oReq.onload = function() {
        alert(this.responseText);
        daliyConfig = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    };
    oReq.open("post", "getLatestCfgHeater.php", true);
    oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    oReq.send(reqArgs);
}
```

and php:

```
error_log("start");
error_log(print_r( $_POST['isDateRequested']));
error_log(print_r( $_POST['date']));

error_log("stop");
```

Unfortunatelly, `php` gives me very strange logs, looks like post data has never been received:

```
[Thu Jan 07 22:44:16 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] start, referer: http://192.168.0.12/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 22:44:16 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: isDateRequested in /var/www/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/getLatestCfgHeater.php on line 6, referer: http://192.168.0.12/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 22:44:16 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] 1, referer: http://192.168.0.12/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 22:44:16 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: date in /var/www/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/getLatestCfgHeater.php on line 7, referer: http://192.168.0.12/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 22:44:16 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] 1, referer: http://192.168.0.12/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 22:44:16 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] stop, referer: http://192.168.0.12/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this. It can send data correctly:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

var_dump($_POST);
?>
<script>getHeaterDailyConfig();
function getHeaterDailyConfig(){
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var d = new Date()
            now = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate()].join('-');
            var reqArgs = "isDateRequested=1&date=" + now;
                            oReq.onload = function() {
                            alert(this.responseText);
                            daliyConfig = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            };
            oReq.open("post", "index.php", true);
            oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            oReq.send(reqArgs);

    }

    </script>
```

and I got data like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["isDateRequested"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["date"]=>
  string(8) "2016-1-7"
}
<script>getHeaterDailyConfig();
function getHeaterDailyConfig(){
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var d = new Date()
            now = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate()].join('-');
            var reqArgs = "isDateRequested=1&date=" + now;
                            oReq.onload = function() {
                            alert(this.responseText);
                            daliyConfig = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            };
            oReq.open("post", "index.php", true);
            oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            oReq.send(reqArgs);

    }

    </script>
```